# Lock file for writing/deleting while allowing any process to read

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I am developing an application in C# (.NET), and am having trouble dealing with file locking.

- My main application (A) needs read/write access to a certain file.
- A separate application (B) needs read access to the same file.
- I need to prevent the user from editing or deleting the file while my application (A) is running. The application (A) is long-running. The file must not be deleted while (A) is running, even when it is not actively being read from or written to.

I have full control of the source of (A) and (B), so I can modify either of them.

How can I stop a user from modifying/deleting a file while application (A) is running, while allowing application (A) to read/write, and application (B) to read?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `FileShare.Read` to only allow reads from other applications. You can lock the file by having a stream open while the application A runs. You need a `NonClosingStreamWrapper` to avoid disposing the stream when you dispose your `StreamWriter` (this happens automatically with `using`)

`NonClosingStreamWrapper` by **Jon Skeet** can be found from [here](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/)

### Example

When application starts use this to lock the file

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
```

When writing to a file use

```
using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(new NonClosingStreamWrapper(fileStream)))
{
    // File writing as usual
}
```

When application ends use this to release the file

```
fileStream.Close();
```

Comment: This solves my problem. Something to note, however, is that StreamWriter will close the underlying stream (and thus unlock the file) when it is disposed, so you have to work around that. I've been using NonClosingStreamWrapper from Jon Skeet's MiscUtils.

Comment: @Joviee Thanks. The answer is now edited to note those things you said.

Comment: I know this is ancient, but I failed to find anything newer/better for (I am having the exact same problem as the OP) - and the link doesn't seem to be helpful anymore.
VS is telling me that it cannot find the "NonClosingStreamWrapper" namespace. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, a locking of the file is not to prevent user deleting the file, but inform user running another instance of the application that the file is "in use" by another user. This is expecially useful if multiple users are opening r/w a file into a shared folder.
In such scenario, instead of locking the file at filesystem level, would be much more easier to use a "lock file" generated when Appication (A) opens the file. Thus, any other application, would notice that a lock file exist (you can name it using the same filename but different extension), and also inside the locking file you can write who and when someone have aquired the lock. Application (B) can now respond to user... "The file appear to be under modification by user xxx from machine yyy, do you really want to load it ?"

Of course, the application must remove the lock file when the application file is no longer in use or when the application terminates. In the "unfortunate" case that a crash leave the lock on filesystem, user can just respond yes to the warning request, or can manually delete it to free the lock.

Hope this helps,

Paolo Marani

Comment: Could you use both: a lock file and a file system lock on the lock file? If an application locks the lock file and the application crashes, the file would be automatically unlocked. In this case, when the application tries to access the lock file and it's successful, it may safely assume that it's OK because there's actually no one using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to lock the file, to prevent writing or deleting, but you don't want to change the file.

I use this to lock a zip file which I use later, so it can be read by others, but can't be altered or changed.
If I use the answer of @Cloudanger, I can't read the zip file anymore in other processes.

```
FileStream fileStreamSslFile = new FileStream(zipFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

Answer (score -1):

though I have not used it, but named `Mutex` can save your day. Before opening a file in application A, create a mutext like this:

```
Mutex(bool initiallyOwned, string name, out bool createdNew)
```

pass file name as second parameter.

now when you open a file in application B, again use `Mutex` if `out` parameter `createdNew` is false then file is already opened by A so you can only read it.

Comment: How will this prevent a user from deleting the file, say, through Windows Explorer?

Comment: @Joviee if you have opened file exclusively then it will pervent other processes from deleting it, but then it might crop up other issues like other processes not even able to read it. This will work only in your two (or future) applications and cannot stop someone using explorer, command line etc to delete file.