# Access denied Error when appending text using File.Append in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am having 4 different threads in my application which writes log to a single text file.

I have used lock functionality in all different threads to properly write into the file and it works as expected without issues. The code is below:

```
lock(fileLocker)
{
    using(StreamWriter sw = File.Append("log.txt"))
    {
         sw.WriteLine("some text");
    }
}
```

The above code throws error (File is in used by another process) at File.append when someone tries to access the file from windows explorer or even if user access the properties of file from the windows explorer.

Any idea, how to avoid this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't. If it's in use, it can't write on a file in use.

Comment: Yes but how to avoid that, because file is currently in process with my application and writes the log. It happens when someone in-between try to access the file from explorer.

Comment: Nobody should access that file

Comment: Try `Open()`ing the file with `FileShare.None`.

Comment: You can retry writing to the file if it is already opened by someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add your logs into a [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and have a separate worker thread observe this queue. Whenever a new entry added it can first lock the file and then write all current entries from the queue (every successful write should be removed from the queue). But if it fails to lock the file or write then it should just handle the exception and then try again next time.

You can see file locking in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279183/4731319

Answer (score -1):

If the file is in use, you simply cannot write to it.  You can only wait a bit and retry.